# How to determine if electrical panel can be upgraded

Tags: electrical-panel

my electrical panel is 100 amps. I'm wondering is it possible to upgrade this panel? I'm looking to install a Tesla wall charger and in my house I have three fridges, 2 stoves, one washer and dryer and I believe I will not have enough power for the Tesla wall charger

[image]

[image]

Comment: Timing can be important.  Running the charger when everybody is sleeping(have enough power) is a lot different using the stoves and dryer at same time as charger(tripping main breaker).

Comment: Modern refrigerators don't matter, they actually take less power than a cable TV box.  We need to know if the ranges and dryer(s) are gas or electric.  Really we need to know about every appliance with a double-wide breaker. I gather you are in Canada?  (horizontal panel, NMD90, French but no Spanish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine the size of your electrical service coming to your house. The power company may be providing you a 100A service in which case you could install a 600A panel and it wouldn't make any difference.

You should be able to contact the PoCo and ask them about your service drop. If they're feeding you only 100A, then you'll have to look into an upgrade to a 200A service (including a new meter, which should be on the PoCo, and possibly a new meter pan, which is likely on you). Once you've actually got 200A being fed to your house, then you can install a new 200A panel, or, if you install a meter-main, then you could run 100A to this panel and 100A to a separate panel in the garage for the EV chargers and any other new circuits.

Comment: I'm asking an honest question to the electricians here that are smarter than me because inquiring minds want to know:   It would appear that with 2 100 amp breakers, each breaker would be on separate hot legs, each feeding separate buses, providing 200 amps.  What's the difference between 2 100 amp breakers and 1 200 amp breaker in a service panel. Anyway, I really like FreeMan's advice / answer. The existing panel looks like a great installation and not in need of upgrades. Swapping out the meter base to provide a separate feed to another panel is a great idea.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson - the difference is that typical home service (in the USA) is two phases, and the amp rating is the amps supplied for each phase. A terminology thing. Your electric vehicle plug has an amps rating that counts on getting those amps from each phase.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson To further clarify your question: a "single" 100 amp breaker (if you could find such a thing ) would allow 100 amps @ 120 volts while the dual breaker in the photo allows 100 amps @ 240 volts.

Comment: @DoxyLover      Thanks for the comment, but I disagree that the US has 2 phase...it's either single phase or three phase in a sinusoidal waveform.  Single phase is one wave form that varies between 120 volts "positive" and 120volts "negative" providing 240 volts across the two hots and 120 volts between a hot and neutral   at 60 hertz. The actual voltages are  higher, but average out to 120/240.   It looks like the 100 amp  breakers are handle tied so I'm still confused about the diff between 2 100 amp breakers and a single 200 amp breaker.   Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson You are right that the US is single phase but dual leg. With the legs 180 degrees out of phase, you get 240 volts hot-hot and 120 volts hot-neutral. A single breaker only protects one hot so it must go to a load connected to neutral, 120 volts, because the other hot wouldn't be protected. With a dual breaker, both hots are protected so you can connect a load hot-hot, 240 volts, or two separate loads hot-neutral (MWBC) for 120 volts at twice the current. [continued below]

Comment: [continued from above] In any case, a dual breaker provides twice the wattage as a single breaker, either by doubling the voltage (240 volt load) or doubling the current (MWBC, total twice the amperage).